# IF function in H2 for MySQL compatibility

Tags: mysql, h2

I'm using H2 (with MySQL compatibility mode) to write some automated tests against our software that uses MySQL. Unfortunately, it seems like H2 does not have have the `IF` function that many of our queries use. Short of rewriting our application queries with something like DECODE, is their a good way to create the if function, say as an Alias?

The error that I'm getting:

```
WARNING: Failed to execute: SELECT IF(true,'TRUE!!','FALSE!!!') because: Function "IF" not found; SQL statement:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ended up just rewriting queries to use functions compatible with both database - H2, MySql.  In my case, the functions in question were replaced with IFNULL.

Comment: `CASEWHEN` is another alternative I think.

Answer (score 10):

I've just had the same issue, and I resolved it with `CASE/WHEN/THEN` SQL statement. So you can rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN true THEN 'TRUE!!' ELSE 'FALSE!!!' END;
```

Surely it's more verbose, but it fits both H2 and MySQL.

Comment: Has another advantage over MySql IF, it is almost standard implementation so it does decouple the query from the database used and thus makes for a better design overall

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can create the if function as an alias:

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS `IF` AS $$
    String ifFunction(boolean condition, String exp1, String exp2){
        if(condition) {
            return exp1;
        } else {
            return exp2;
        }
    }
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for strings. I need an IF for strings and number, though. I've written a new question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595970/create-alias-which-works-for-strings-and-numbers-in-h2